# Static Website Redirect HTTP to HTTPS with GCP Load Balancer with

Tags: https, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing, http-redirect

I need to redirect my website from **http to https**, I have my static website in Google Cloud Storage Bucket pointed to Load Balance with http & https enabled.

**Example:**

> http://ex.com = > https://ex.com
>   http://www.ex.com = > https://www.ex.com

The https://ex.com, https://www.ex.com both work just fine, however, I just need the http redirect so that I can reach Secure Service

Since I am having a static website I hope I can only handle this in Load Balance, Can some one help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late, but Google added a fix for the issue.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904733

Answer (score 3):

At this time, this is not possible via a Google HTTP Load Balancer feature. There is a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904733).

You could add JavaScript to your pages. However, this will not guarantee HTTPS redirection. Usually, just adding this to the home page and a few key pages will get most of your traffic to HTTPS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (location.protocol != 'https:')
  {
   location.href = 'https:' + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: In complement of @johnhanley answer, you can add a second frontend to your Loadbalancer, this one for HTTP protocol. By the way, the HTTP request will be routed to your site, and the Javascript can do the redirection.

Comment: This issue tracker is from 2015 still now we dint receive any fix for this issue Its a basic feature at least google might have added a note in the docs of Hosting a static website, Not sure Javascript redirection will be a good solution.

Comment: Guillaume Can I have a example or a link for second frontend to your Loadbalancer.

Comment: Have you tried adding this line to your nginx.conf as a workaround as some people suggest in the **[Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35904733)** comments?

`if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}`

More info **[here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#target-proxies)**. There is a similar **[SO case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58246708/redirect-http-to-https-google-cloud-load-balance)**

Comment: I have a static website so in my case I am using google cloud storage that is pointed to LB so no compute engine cant set nginx.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old one.

But now you can do this directly in the load balancer. Follow this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect). In particular, you want to go to the "Redirecting traffic to your HTTPS load balancer" [section](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect#partial-http-lb).