# Can't get HTTPS working on google cloud storage bucket with load balancer

Tags: https, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to set up an https cert on a static website which is hosted in a google cloud storage bucket with uniform permissions.

I obtained a cert from ssls.com and I believe I successfully put it into the google host load balancer. It is the other configurations that I think are causing the problem. When I go to the www. location of the site, it still does not work with https:\.

I have tried the following instructions except without using zones for the buckets or multiple buckets as I didn't require that:

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-backend-buckets-to-load-balancers

I have edited my DNS records so the relevant portions appear as follows:

[image]

I added the CNAME records days ago and added the A record about 12 hours ago.

Here is an image of the load balancer status:

[image: Screenshot of load balancer status]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your DNS server to point [www.jpdgallery.com](http://www.jpdgallery.com) to the load balancer's IP address 35.201.101.158. Notice the TTL value before changing anything. After the change, you will have to wait at least that long for updates to occur.

Comment: I had added the A record before posting my record. I updated my question above to reflect that. Should I remove the CNAME record once the A record is added?

Comment: *before posting my question.

Comment: You added a CNAME pointing to what? Load Balancers use an IP address, this means you need to use an A record and not a CNAME.

Comment: Before I had made the load balancer, I had created a CNAME entry to the jpdgallery domain as shown above so that the URL would direct to index.html in that bucket (as I configured the bucket to default to index.html). I added the load balancer, and the A record to the jpdgallery DNS entries, but HTTPS did not work. I removed the CNAME and the site went down, so I put it back up. Maybe I didn't give it long enough for the A record to take over, but it seemed like the A record had fully propagated on https://dnschecker.org/.

Comment: Your CNAME record points to Cloud Storage. That bypasses the Load Balancer.

Comment: When I removed the CNAME, the site stopped working. How long should I give it?

Comment: That depends. Can be up to a day for the DNS changes to propagate. Your TTL is set to 1 hour, so at least that long.  Your A record is not correct. It should look like your CNAME. Replace `jpd-lb-forwarding-rule` with `www` and change the TTL to a much longer value (like one day).

Comment: That seemed to work in less than 12 hours, but I am now realizing that these load balancers don't forward http to https. Thats another issue which I'll try to tackle now. Thanks for your help John!

Comment: @JakeDurell - You are welcome. Typically, you will implement HTTP->HTTPS redirection in your web server. Since you are using a Cloud Storage based static website, you can implement redirection thru several methods. Let me know if you create a new question. Take a look at my answer here for an easy method for static websites: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58271886/8016720